# How to calculate transaction fees collected by a validator

Tags: staking, fees, transaction, rewards

I know that 50% of the transaction fees on Solana are burned and 50% are given to the validator that included the transaction in the proposed block. I am unable to understand how can we find out how much transaction fees did a validator maken in an epoch.

I know that there is a `getInflationReward` method in the [RPC API](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getinflationreward), but I think it only returns the inflation reward. Is there any method that returns the total transaction fees collected as well for an epoch ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will require a combination of things.

- find out the slots for which the validator was the leader using `getLeaderSchedule` https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getleaderschedule
- get each of the blocks using `getBlock`, specifying that you want the rewards for the block https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getblock
- check all of the `'fee'` rewards in the block, and sum them up

Comment: I did try, the getBlock function but the "rewards" array comes out to be empty everytime. Is there any reason for this ? But it comes populated for really old blocks (like a year ago). Is there any reason for this ?